# How do I view the document info panel in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As the title says, I'm having trouble finding out where the document info panel in Illustrator is.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD. This question might well get closed, as it seems more of a tech problem. In any way, the version of AI might be useful to know. There is also a good chance that if you search within AI it will tell you, or you might find it under view/window.

Answer (score 2):

To display the panel, choose Window > Document Info.

To view a different type of information, select an option from the panel menu: Document, Objects, Graphic Styles, Brushes, Spot Color Objects, Pattern Objects, Gradient Objects, Fonts, Linked Images, Embedded Images, and Font Details.

To view information on only the selected object, choose Selection Only from the panel menu. Leaving this option deselected lists information about the entire document.

To save a copy of the file information as a text file, choose Save from the panel menu. Specify a name and location, and then click Save.

To view artboard dimensions, click the Artboard tool, choose Document from the panel menu, and then click to select the artboard you want to view.